# Codable variable inside Codable struct causes error

Tags: swift, protocols, codable, decodable, encodable

Please take a look at my code:

#### No errors

```swift
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Double
    var birthday: Date
    
    var selectedItem: Car
}

struct Car: Codable {
    var companyName: String
    var creationDate: Date
}

struct iPhone: Codable {
    var model: String
    var creationDate: Date
    var isScreenBroken: Bool = true
}
```

#### Build error

```swift
struct Person: Codable { // "Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'", "Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'"
    var name: String
    var age: Double
    var birthday: Date
    
    var selectedItem: Codable // I've changed this line
}

struct Car: Codable {
    var companyName: String
    var creationDate: Date
}

struct iPhone: Codable {
    var model: String
    var creationDate: Date
    var isScreenBroken: Bool = true
}
```

> Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

> Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

I don't understand why is this happening. It knows that `selectedItem` is conforming to `Encodable` & `Decodable`:

```swift
var selectedItem: Codable
```

I'm new to protocols in Swift so please when answering try to explain what's happening here.

Thanks!

Comment: how it knows selectedItem is conforming to Codable ? Obviously selected item is not Car type anymore.

Comment: @zeytin ```var selectedItem: Codable```

Comment: It would have to decode `selectedItem` to a specific type, which isn’t declared. Just stating that it conforms to `Codable` does not help with decoding if it does not have a type.

Comment: You could make a new type for `selectedItem` that conforms to Codable, or set it to a concrete type like `Int` or `String`.

Comment: Can you please provide an answer and give an example? @Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem for the compiler here is that normally when a type is defined to conform to `Codable` then the compiler synthesises code for you to make `Person` in this case conform to the protocol. It does this by creating an implementation of `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` and one of `func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws` for you.

But when you change `selectedItem` to be of type `Codable` then the compiler can no longer synthesise these methods since it needs to know exactly what properties the type of `selectedItem` has to correctly generate the code.

What you need to do here is to use [generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

```
struct Person<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Double
    var birthday: Date

    var selectedItem: T
}

struct Car: Codable {
    var companyName: String
    var creationDate: Date
}

struct iPhone: Codable {
    var model: String
    var creationDate: Date
    var isScreenBroken: Bool = true
}
```

Then the compiler is happy again and you can use it like

```
let person = Person(name: "Joe", age: 40, birthday: date, selectedItem: Car(companyName: "Ford", creationDate: Date()))
```